# what is parse error: naked expression at top level?

Tags: haskell, syntax

I was trying to get the length of each element, given a nested list; and I also I want to get rid of the repeated length.

For example, a nested list `[[1],[1,2],[4..5]]` should give me `[1,2]`.

I can do it in the interactive by nub `(map  length  [[1],[1,2],[4..5]])`. But if I write a file with the following code:

```
Import Data.List
getLen :: [[a]] ->[Int]
getLen xs = nub (map length xs)
```

I got the error saying:

> "Parse error: naked expression at top level"

What does this error mean and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the parser, `Import Data.List` looks like an application of the data constructor `Import` with the data constructor `Data.List` as its argument.

Since this error occurred during parsing, the compiler has not yet figured out that neither of the data constructors `Import` or `Data.List` actually exist, but it does know that an expression like this is not allowed at the top level.

Of course, in this case it was just a typo as @augustss pointed out.

Answer (score 9):

Simple change: it's `import` not `Import`.