# Haskell Parse Error - Naked Expression at Top Level

Tags: haskell

I have a haskell file test.hs.
In this file I have written a function

```
doubleMe x: x + x
```

this is the only function in this file test.hs.
In the ghci command prompt I have typed ":l test.hs" without quotes.
The following error comes up:

```
compiling main  <test.hs interpreted>
test.hs:1:1 Parse error: naked expression at top level
Failed: modules loaded:none
```

What will be the cause of this error.

I have gone through
[Haskell Error - Naked Expression at Top Level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885148/haskell-error-naked-expression-at-top-level)

and

[what is parse error: naked expression at top level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208622/what-is-parse-error-naked-expression-at-top-level)

It did not help.

Comment: That looks like you're trying to write Python, not Haskell. Their syntaxes are not the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need `=` rather than `:`, so:

```
doubleMe x = x + x
```

---

If you try to use `:`, GHC parses this as using the `:` operator on `doubleMe x` and `x + x`. This is a function application, so it is an expression (an expression is basically a series of tokens that has a result). Since it isn't wrapped in a function or variable declaration it is a "naked expression", and this is an error.

Comment: re: last paragraph - If that was an expression, it would be parsed by default as `(doubleMe x) : (x + x)`, because `(:)` has smaller priority than `(+)`.